# Replace \n by a space while reading a message

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, lexer, javacc

I need to read a message that is written on many lines, for now I'm skipping the new line character `\n` but I need to replace the `\n` by a space while reading the message ( before compiling it )

**exemple:**

```
message: " I'm going
to parse
this
message"
```

If I skip the `\n` the message to parse will be `I'm goingto parsethismessage`
but I need it to be `I'm going to parse this message`

Is there a way to replace `\n` by a space while going through the grammar in javacc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your token manager rules look something like this

```
SKIP: { < "\n" > }
TOKEN: { < SPACE: " " > }
...
```

Replace them with

```
TOKEN: { < SPACE: " " | "\n" > }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by adding this as special token

```
SPECIAL_TOKEN:
{
    < SPACE : ((" ")+ ) | < new_line > | < new_line> (" ")+ >
|  <# new_line : "\n" >
}
```